# NS3 Pyviz Visualization Writing Value Problem

Tags: 20.04, graphics, virtualbox, python

When I run ns3 visualization tool, Values Are written like this,Numbers are overlapping
What should I do?
I run this in virtualBox ubuntu version 20.04.3 LTS

[Pyviz Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUNaP.png)

Comment: Right, horizontal texts are "doubled", vertical texts seem OK. I get the same result. ....... Please also ask at the official ns3 support https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users

Comment: I do not think it has anything to do with Ubuntu ask at the NS3 support as @Knud Larsen